# Are areas filled with an oily texture common in jamon serrano

Tags: food-safety, meat

I bought a whole jamon serrano right before christmas and have kept in at approx. 20°C and between 55-65% humidity. I have enjoyed every slice of delicious meat and have now started to cut the last part of it; the *punta* (end piece). However I suddenly uncovered a canal running under the skin which secretes a substance very similar to cooking oil. The smell is heavily bitter, like nuts gone bad.

Since I don't know the details on how a jamon is prepared, I wonder if this is expected, or is it a sign that the area is somehow contaminated?

Comment: In case you were worried about getting sick and want a quick partial answer: the oil has just gone rancid - it's not contamination, just what happens to oil over time. (It happens in nuts too since they contain plenty of oil.)

Comment: @Jefromi Thanks for the quick heads-up, that was in fact my initial concern :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have the necessary points to comment I will make one or two assumptions.

Spanish Jamon is a salt cured ham. I suspect, if you got your ham bone-out, then the residue oil is where the meat closest to where the bone was did not cure as well.

Make sure you buy your Jamon ham from a reliable and recognized source (*Denominación de Origen*). Even if you saved a little on price, with food, it is not the greatest plan.

As I live in the US I only enjoy that delicacy when I travel to Spain. I do not trust any of the US imports.

You just haven't lived until you have tried Jamón de Guijuelo!!!

Comment: That is a pretty accurate description - the canal does in fact run very close to the bone. Unfortunately I no longer have the box it came in so I cannot verify where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

This happens from time to time, but is not something to be expected in your jamón. My household goes through 2-3 hams a year, not counting store-bought sliced packs, and I can only recall cutting into rancid fat maybe once.

Like @Randy said, make sure your jamón has a legitimate Denominación de Origen, everything else is a gamble.